# Deployment of a Rails app: How should the DB be loaded and filled during the very first deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, database-schema

I'm currently in the process of refactoring my deployment process of my Rails apps.

The one thing that I'm still not clear about is how to load the DB schema of a newly deployed app.

I use [Mina](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/), as it is much faster than Capistrano. I asked my question in their issue tracker, but I didn't get an answer so far, so I try my luck here again:

From [What's the correct way to load the DB schema? On "setup"? Or on first "deploy"?](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/issues/652):

> I'm still unsure when to load my DB schema when setting up a new application using Mina.
>
> I know about invoke `:'rails:db_schema_load'` in deploy, but I only need to run it the very first deploy. So why not move it to setup? Or at least only run it the very first time - because now I have to uncomment it manually after the first run, otherwise:
>
> ```
> rake aborted!
>       ActiveRecord::ProtectedEnvironmentError: You are attempting to run a destructive action against your 'production' database.
> ```

The deployment code looks like this:

```
task :deploy do
  invoke :'git:ensure_pushed'

  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_schema_load' # Only do the first time, then comment out, please!
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    command %{#{fetch(:rails)} db:seed} # Also, only do the first time!
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'
  end
end
```

What I don't like about it is the there are two lines that need to be commented out after first deploy. I'm looking for a way to do this automatically. My attempts so far were:

1. To put the lines in question into the `setup` task, but this doesn't seem to load the full Rails stack yet (it's only creating and symlinking some directories).
2. To try to decide programmatically whether a deployment is the first one or not, but I couldn't figure out how myself.

Again, I asked another question: [How to find out whether it's the first deployment (in the deploy command itself)?](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/issues/652):

> I'd like to execute some commands depending on whether a deployment is the first one or not.
>
> In the following pseudo code, I'm using a hypothetical `first_deploy?` method:
>
> ```
> invoke :'rails:db_schema_load' if first_deploy?
> ...
> command %{#{fetch(:rails)} db:seed} if first_deploy?
> ```

But again, no reactions received.

Anybody has a strong opinion on this topic? How would you do this with Capistrano, or any other automated deployment?

Comment: I think you need to create the database first

Comment: Try: `invoke : 'rake db:create db:migrate' if first_deploy?`

Comment: Alternatively you can just SSH into the server and run `rake db:create` - the rest should function after that

Comment: I think I was not clear enough. I want to create and populate the DB automatically using the deploy script. And sadly the `first_deploy?` method does not exist, it's pseudo code.